# Grep regex to capture ip socket without port

Tags: regex, sockets, sed, grep, cut

I have in my file the following log:

```
Aug 27 18:41:44 Testlab nixc[27354]: 207416484 {10.20.21.106:52907 10.20.21.27:80} http traffic
```

I would like to extract only the ips example:

```
10.22.39.106 10.242.29.27
```

I've tried

```
grep -E -o '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}.*[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' log
```

I still get

```
10.20.21.106:52907 10.20.21.27
10.20.21.106:52907 10.20.21.27
10.20.21.106:52907 10.20.21.27
10.20.21.106:52907 10.20.21.27
```

maybe some `sed` or `cut` will do the trick?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work with `grep`:

```
\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}
```

I posted a link to a site where you can test regex like jsfidle but aparently I can't post links yet, google it ;)

EDITED:

Here ya go:

```
egrep -o '[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}' /var/log/auth.log >> test.log
```

Comment: The first one works interpreted as `perl`, with `-Po` switches.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `grep` statement with one of the following..

Using the `-E` option *Interprets the PATTERN as an extended regular expression.* The `-o` option will *show only the part of a matching line that matches the PATTERN*.

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' log
```

or using the `-P` option *Interprets the PATTERN as a Perl regular expression*

```
grep -Po '(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}' log
```

See this regular expression live. [regular expression demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/cO9cL6)

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -Eo '\<(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])' file
```

---

```
# \<(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])
# 
# Assert position at the beginning of a word «\<»
# Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])»
#    Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «25[0-5]»
#       Match the characters “25” literally «25»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “5” «[0-5]»
#    Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «2[0-4][0-9]»
#       Match the character “2” literally «2»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “4” «[0-4]»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
#    Or match regular expression number 3 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «1[0-9]{2}»
#       Match the character “1” literally «1»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{2}»
#          Exactly 2 times «{2}»
#    Or match regular expression number 4 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «[1-9]?[0-9]»
#       Match a single character in the range between “1” and “9” «[1-9]?»
#          Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
# Match the character “.” literally «\.»
# Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])»
#    Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «25[0-5]»
#       Match the characters “25” literally «25»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “5” «[0-5]»
#    Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «2[0-4][0-9]»
#       Match the character “2” literally «2»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “4” «[0-4]»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
#    Or match regular expression number 3 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «1[0-9]{2}»
#       Match the character “1” literally «1»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{2}»
#          Exactly 2 times «{2}»
#    Or match regular expression number 4 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «[1-9]?[0-9]»
#       Match a single character in the range between “1” and “9” «[1-9]?»
#          Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
# Match the character “.” literally «\.»
# Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])»
#    Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «25[0-5]»
#       Match the characters “25” literally «25»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “5” «[0-5]»
#    Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «2[0-4][0-9]»
#       Match the character “2” literally «2»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “4” «[0-4]»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
#    Or match regular expression number 3 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «1[0-9]{2}»
#       Match the character “1” literally «1»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{2}»
#          Exactly 2 times «{2}»
#    Or match regular expression number 4 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «[1-9]?[0-9]»
#       Match a single character in the range between “1” and “9” «[1-9]?»
#          Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
# Match the character “.” literally «\.»
# Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 4 «(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])»
#    Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «25[0-5]»
#       Match the characters “25” literally «25»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “5” «[0-5]»
#    Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «2[0-4][0-9]»
#       Match the character “2” literally «2»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “4” «[0-4]»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
#    Or match regular expression number 3 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «1[0-9]{2}»
#       Match the character “1” literally «1»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{2}»
#          Exactly 2 times «{2}»
#    Or match regular expression number 4 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «[1-9]?[0-9]»
#       Match a single character in the range between “1” and “9” «[1-9]?»
#          Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) and split in characters `{`, `:`, `}` and blanks. Then count fields:

```
awk -F'[{:}[:blank:]]+' '{ print $9, $11 }' infile
```

It yields:

```
10.20.21.106 10.20.21.27
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    {(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}):.+\s(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}:.\d{1,3})}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/_scDYGXhp1CZW6WZ)